# Grunt server task config from external files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, gruntjs

I'm running an Angular.js application and all the task management are made with grunt, for now I have three components that I'm watching in live reload, bower_components, invoices and users, eventually they are going to increase in number, so I would like to know if there's a way to call an external file like components.json and iterate through its n members. Here is my code:

```
// The grunt server settings
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            open: true,
            middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                    connect.static('.tmp'),
                    connect().use(
                        '/bower_components',
                        connect.static('./bower_components')
                    ),
                    connect().use(
                        '/invoices',
                        connect.static(invoicesAppPathConfig.root)
                    ),
                    connect().use(
                        '/users',
                        connect.static(usersAppPathConfig.root)
                    ),
                    connect.static(secureAppPathConfig.app)
                ];
            }
        }
    },
    dist: {
        options: {
            open: true,
            base: '<%= main.dist %>'
        }
    }
}
```

I have already created the component.json file:

```
{"data":[
    {
        "resource":"/bower_components",
        "config":"./bower_components"
    },
    {
        "resource":"/invoices",
        "config":"invoicesAppPathConfig.root"
    },
    {
        "resource":"/users",
        "config":"usersAppPathConfig.root"
    }
]}
```

And in the Gruntfile.js I created this variables, having in mind that I need to iterate in the content of data:

```
var components = require('./components.json');
var data = components.data;
```

Now I have the question, how can I do it this in the code?

```
middleware: function (connect) {
    return [
        connect.static('.tmp'),
        // Here comes the data iteration
        connect.static(secureAppPathConfig.app)
    ];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the next variables:

```
var components = require('./components.json');
var data = components.data;
var arrayComponents = [];
```

Then in the options for livereload iterate the json data and add it to `arrayComponents`:

```
middleware: function (connect){
    arrayComponents.push(connect.static('.tmp'));
    // The modules to be watched are added
    for(var i in data){
        arrayComponents.push(connect().use(data[i].resource, connect.static(data[i].config)));
    }
    arrayComponents.push(connect.static(secureAppPathConfig.app));
    return arrayComponents;
}
```

It works, but maybe it is not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    components: grunt.file.readJSON('components.json'),
    [...]
});
```

More [info on `grunt.file` here](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file)

You can also require it:

```
var components = require('./components.json');
```

Comment: So what do you need specifically?

Comment: Just require it as you do in grunt file